# Get (g) graphics from jpanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics

How do I get the g element from a jpanel in java, how can I pass it to another object draw on it and pass it back. Just to be clear, I can use g or graphics to draw on the jpanel; but cannot seem to pass this to another object to draw on it else where. Thanks in advance, I have searched for a solution and cannot find anything, might be that I am not using the right terminology, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way to pass a `Graphics` object from a `JPanel` to another (helper) object is to pass the object from the `paintComponent` method. This way, you can be sure that the object will always be instantiated.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   myGraphicsHelper.drawStuff(g);
}
```

Comment: Well, I cannot up-vote but this was what I was looking for, Thank you